# How can i store particular table(maria db) in ram and retrieve the data from the ram instead of db

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using maria DB to store the data when I search for the data I don't want my query to hit DB again and again to get data instead is there any way I can store this in ram as a cache so every time I search the search query will not hit the DB it will retrieve the data from the ram.

Comment: That's called a cache. Without more details we can't tell you which of the 23098 approached might fit your problem. If you e.g. need to limit bandwith, a cache server on your side will probably not help much. Does the (underlying) data changes often and is it a problem? Is the table fully independent (which makes the "relational" part of your relational database less relevant), e.g. a key-value-store? A simple cache would be to store a copy of your table/the rows retrieved on your client. I'm sure that is not what you had in mind, but without more details, we don't *know* what you had in mind.

Comment: I'm using a table to store the encrypted data I need to store the data from that table in RAM as decrypted data and every time I will be retrieving the data from ram, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Unfortunately, this makes your problem more complicated, as you don't cache a table, but a result. It will still depend on your setup, e.g. what/who decrypts the data and how and specifically where you get the decryption key from, especially since, if e.g. the client provides the key, you can't use a cache on your side (as it negates the encryption), but, as mentioned, just storing the data in the client app might work (if the data isn't use to join or something). But again, without details about your setup it's impossible to be specific.

Comment: And an additional thought: to get a feel of what a cache setup might look like (without your encryption problem, or rather, not necessarily solving your decryption problem depending on how it looks like exactyl), have a look at e.g. "redis" or "memcached". It might give you some inspiration (and you can maybe pinpoint where in such a generic setup your decryption fits in, and/or if your data and data access fits such a setup).

Comment: But then do you need to encrypt the 'cache'?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MEMORY storage engine as described in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

```
CREATE TABLE test ENGINE=MEMORY
           SELECT ip,SUM(downloads) AS down
           FROM log_table GROUP BY ip;
SELECT COUNT(ip),AVG(down) FROM test;
DROP TABLE test;
```